# Why do some static methods require "()" and other do not?

Tags: java

For example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Foothill {

    static Scanner input;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        input = new Scanner (System.in);
        String[] getNames = new String[5];

        for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++){

            System.out.println("Enter 5 names: ");
            getNames[x] = input.nextLine();
        }

       for(int i = 0; i < **getNames.length**; i++)
        {System.out.print(getNames[i] + ", ");
       }    
    }

    public static String newString(String getNames)
    {
        String newS;

        for(int j = 0; j < **getNames.length()**; j++){

        }
    }
}
```

Is there a reason in the main method my string Array getNames.length doesn't require "()", but im getting an error the newString method below it?

Comment: You should really look into the difference between methods and fields.

Answer (score 8):

Method calls always require `()`, so if there's no `()`, it's not a method.

For arrays, [`length` is a member variable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html), not a method, but in [`String`, `length()` is an actual method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length()).  Also, neither is `static`.

Comment: Thanks, so in the example I provided, what would be the reason that in the main method's for-loop getNames.length does not require a "()" but the method under it does?

Comment: @Ray Because `getNames` is an array.

Comment: I understand it's an Array -- it's an array in both the main method and the newString method. So why is the syntax different?

Comment: @Ray I think you may have confused yourself by giving two different variables the same name. In the main method, `getNames` is an array (`String[]`), whereas in the newString method it is just a `String` (one of the elements of the array).

Comment: @Anders -- oh you are right. Thank you. I guess my follow up question is that I am trying to pass the elements of the Array or the array itself to the newString method. The requirement is to get 5 names, put them in an array, create another method that parses through the elements of the array and returns the concatenated second character of every name. So if you have "Bob", "Tom", "Don", "Jon, Ron", it will return "ooooo".

Comment: I think I just answered my own question --arrays are pass-by-reference so it is more like a pointer. This is what my newString method looks like:

public static String newString(String[] getNames)
 {
  String newS;
  
  for(int j = 0; j < getNames.length; j++){
   
   newS = getNames[j].charAt[1];
  }
 }